# Odoo Filter many2one field on load

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In my module I have a many2one field to select workers for a particular task. According to the requirement that field should only display the workers in the current user's department. Simply this is the code,

```
 _columns = {
    'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee'),
}
```

My problem is how to perform such filteration for a field on load? I tried using functional field in a domain in view xml. but It seems functional field gets its value when saving the particular record.

Also I tried adding domain to the field itself, here get_current_user_department is a function returns the department id

```
_columns = {
    'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee',domain=[('department_id.id','=',get_current_user_department)]),
}
```

This generates following error,

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

Any suggestion to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can take one field for storing current user department you can set default value of current user department.

```
default_department_id = fields.Many2one('employee.department', 
                                        string='My User',
                                        default='get_department')
```

Now you need to create function for set default department.

After that you need to write in XML:

```
<field name="default_department_id" invisible="1"/>
<field name="employee_id" 
       domain="
           [('department_id','=',default_department_id)]
       "/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a new many2one field to save the current user department ID and put the value of the department at loading with default_get() method.
Then after, you can put this field on a domain to filter employee that are in the same department than the user.

Comment: Thanks. yeah i tried with an integer field and it works!! problem is that field also get save in the database.  can we stop that?

Comment: Make the field 'department_id' readonly on the view and it doesn't be saved.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see another solution. It's just a new column on the table in DB but always empty, so no more size on DB.

Comment: I see. Problem is there are several other filtrations in that class.   I am looking for a method to set a domain or id list in the runtime without creating additional columns for each filtration . Thanks a lot Quentin

Comment: So you can use a fields.function to make the filtration. You have an example here : http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unifield-team/unifield-wm/trunk/view/head:/msf_config_locations/stock_configuration.py#L308

Comment: yeah. but the problem is we can't use functional field in domain filter as they evaluates when the record save to the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85186/discussion-between-quentin-theuret-and-javatar).